# How to optimize HTTP polling in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, axios, polling, keep-alive

I'm developing a NodeJS service that continuously polls a REST API to get state changes of a large number of resources in near real-time. No other protocol is available.

The polling interval is 5 seconds. The number of resources is usually between 100-500, so let's consider:

- Usually it does 50 HTTP requests per second
- Response often takes more than 5 seconds so requests for the same request may overlap

Often the load average gets to over 8.00 (in a 8 core vm) and/or the app crashes.

I want to ensure that the resource usage is as minimal as possible while handling this workload.

Here's what I've done:

- HTTP2 is available (but unsupported by axios?)
- Set `process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 8`
- Use the axios library to make async requests
- Reusing the same axios instance for all requests
- Use an HTTPSAgent with keep-alive

The relevant code:

```
'use strict'
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 8

const axios = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://api.example.com',
    httpsAgent: new HTTPS.Agent({
        keepAlive: true,
        //maxSockets: 256,
        //maxFreeSockets: 128,
        scheduling: 'fifo',
        timeout: 1000 * 15
    }),
    timeout: 1000 * 15,
})

loadResource(id){
    return axios.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `/resource/${id}`
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        process.logger.error('Error with request (...)')
    })
    .then((res) => {
        handle(res)
    })
}

for(let id of [1,2,3,4,(...)]){
    setInterval(() => loadResource(id), 5000)
}

handle(res){...}
```

What I'm considering:

- Waiting for a response before making the new request (and looking for the best approach to do this)

What else can be done to handle the requests in an optimal way?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use polling in the first place?  Is there no better protocol available for this API?  Have you also considered that using the same agent with keepalive, responses via HTTP/1.1 will block other responses?  HTTP/2 would be a better choice, if available.  Otherwise, you're going to need multiple connections anyway.

Comment: HTTP2 is being used. There's no other alternative transport though. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so the overlapping requests part... is that a requirement?  Over time, this will build up to a load that will eventually crash.  Is there any reason why you wouldn't wait for a request for a resource to complete before attempting to fetch it again?  (In other words, I wouldn't use `setInterval()`.  I'd use a semaphore, or at least some logic that handles the response (or failure) of a resource load to queue loading that resource again.)

Comment: FYI, thread pool does not affect networking at all.

Comment: That's likely the main thing to improve upon and I'm currently seeking the best approach to handle this parallel queue. Using a `setTimeout()` to reschedule after getting the response also comes to mind but there must already be an abstraction around this or the semaphore.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-semaphore

Comment: I might be wrong, but does Axios actually use http2? I would at least _not_ use setInterval, but use setTimeout instead and schedule a new request after you received the last response.

Comment: Shit, both of the things in my comment was already mentioned.